# Create Haskell-like where construct with scala macroexpressions

Tags: scala, haskell, macros, dsl

Is it possible to create something looking like haskell `where-clause` in scala with help of scala-macro expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it looks like that Macro or Scala-meta will not help. The only option is to create a compiler plugin for that.